# NoReverseMatch for SlugField?

Tags: django

I 'slugified' the `team_name` field for model `Team` so that spaces would display more beautifully in the URL.  However when I try to switch the pk variable that you pass into the URL, I get a NoReverseMatch for the slug.  It is working fine for with `team_name`.

**models**

```
class Team(models.Model):

    team_name = models.CharField(max_length=25, unique=True)
    team_name_slug = models.SlugField(max_length=25, unique=True)
```

---

**views + template URL (this doesn't work)**

```
def team_public_profile(request, pk):
    team = get_object_or_404(Team, team_name_slug=pk)
    ... other code

---

<form action="{% url 'team_public_profile' pk=team_name_slug %}">
```

---

**this works**

```
def team_public_profile(request, pk):
    team = get_object_or_404(Team, team_name=pk)
    ... other code

---

<form action="{% url 'team_public_profile' pk=team_name %}">
```

Comment: Would you mind to show your `urls.py`?

Comment: @nik_m Thank you.  That was the issue, I changed my url regex from `(?P<pk>[\w]+)` to `(?P<pk>[\w-]+)`.  Now it is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to populate the `team_name_slug` using `django.utils.text.slugify` on the Team model `save()` method like:

```
  from django.utils.text import slugify

  class Team(models.Model):
      ...

      def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.team_name:
            self.team_name_slug = slugify(self.team)
        super(Team, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Your URL should look like:

```
  url(r'^teams/(?P<team_name_slug>[\w-]+)/$', views.team_public_profile, name='team_public_profile')
```

And your View + Template:

```
def team_public_profile(request, team_name_slug):
    team = get_object_or_404(Team, team_name_slug=team_name_slug)
    ... other code
```

---

```
 <form action="{% url 'team_public_profile' team_name_slug=team_name_slug %}">
```

Comment: The problem was in my URL regex.  I did not have `-` in `(?P<pk>[\w-]+)`.  Thanks.